# Display Alphabetic group in Acronyms list

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, alphabet

I made an acronyms list with the `glossaries` package, here is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, french, openright, oneside, fleqn]{report} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{3gpp}{3GPP}{The 3rd Generation Partnership Project} 
\newacronym{amps}{AMPS}{Advanced Mobile Phone System} 
\newacronym{apd}{APD}{Avalanche photodiode} 
\newacronym{ask}{ASK}{Amplitude Shift Keying} 
\newacronym{bbu}{BBU}{Baseband Unit} 
\newacronym{ber}{BER}{Bit Error Rate} 
\newacronym{bs}{BS}{Base Station}

\begin{document}
    
\acrshort{3gpp}, \acrshort{amps}, \acrshort{apd}, \acrshort{ask}, \acrshort{bbu}, \acrshort{ber}, \acrshort{bs},

\printglossary[title=Acronymes et Abréviations, toctitle=Liste des acronymes et des abréviations, type=\acronymtype]
    
\end{document}
```

And instead of getting this :

[image]

I would like to get something like this :

[image]

Where there is alphabetical grouping. I want to display the alphabet letters order. And getting the page numbers hyperref if it's possible !

Comment: You can try the `indexgroup` style.

Comment: Can you be more clear please ?

Comment: Add `style=indexgroup` to the options of `\printglossary`.

Comment: Worked perfectly ! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should result in the expected ouput. I have added `style=indexgroup` to the options of `\printglossaries` as well as the `hyperref` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, french, openright, oneside, fleqn]{report} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{3gpp}{3GPP}{The 3rd Generation Partnership Project} 
\newacronym{amps}{AMPS}{Advanced Mobile Phone System} 
\newacronym{apd}{APD}{Avalanche photodiode} 
\newacronym{ask}{ASK}{Amplitude Shift Keying} 
\newacronym{bbu}{BBU}{Baseband Unit} 
\newacronym{ber}{BER}{Bit Error Rate} 
\newacronym{bs}{BS}{Base Station}

\begin{document}
    
\acrshort{3gpp}, \acrshort{amps}, \acrshort{apd}, \acrshort{ask}, \acrshort{bbu}, \acrshort{ber}, \acrshort{bs},

\printglossary[title=Acronymes et Abréviations, toctitle=Liste des acronymes et des abréviations, type=\acronymtype,style=indexgroup]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly ! I appreciate your help :)